# php/mysql search for date and send email if date is today

Tags: php, mysql

I stored with dates in this format 6th July,2012 in my table. I want to loop through them and send an email to the admin if the date is today's date. 
i tried this but think i need to concert the date format first.

```
SELECT email, name, phone_no FROM table WHERE TO_DAYS(date)=To_DAYS(NOW());
 If true then send email to admin.
 //eg. John's birthday is today. Pls call him on 00001332424;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should convert to native mysql date/time formats first. Storing as a date as a string is all fine and dandy if you never have to manipulate that date. But as soon as you do, then you're in for a world of pain - can't uses indexes, have to convert every string EVERY TIME you run a query, etc...

Once you've converted that string to a native date field, then it's a simple matter of

```
SELECT .... WHERE datefield=CURDATE();
```

To give you an idea what's possible once you've got your dates in 'native' format, here's the mysql date/time manipulation functions: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

there's lots of them, but almost all only work on native date fields, not on arbitrary strings (except the ones that convert string<->native).

Comment: insightful..will take more look. I designed the system for someone who really needed the dates in string formats because it confused them. Now I guess i have to save the dates in native too so it helps in my queries.

Comment: Was thinking...is there any function in php to change the date from string to native on the fly? so it could be used in queries. The reverse is possible. right?

Comment: There's str_to_date(), but using it on the fly will be HIGHLY inefficient. you won't be able to use indexes, you'll be convert **all** the dates EVERY TIME you run the query, forcing full table scans, yada yada yada. performance will stink worse than an unflushed toilet at a music festival.